# Haskell Concat-Typeclass

Tags: haskell, concatenation, typeclass

I wondered if there is a defined typeclass in Haskell, which declares concatenation.

For lists there is `++` and `concat`. But of course there are other types which are concatable.

Example:

```
type Valuater = A -> [Int]
concatValuater :: [Valuater] -> Valuater
concatValuater vs = \a -> concat [v a | v <- vs]
```

Isn't there a typeclass for `concat`?

Comment: I think you are looking for `Monoid` too - but just in case there is a `concat` for foldables: [`concat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:concat) - plus you can always have a look yourself using hoogle or hayoo: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=m+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+m+a

Comment: `concat` for foldables just uses `(++)`. It takes advantage of the fact that a `Foldable t` containing lists `t [a]` can be folded over to concatenate those lists with `(++)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @JAbrahamson has said, `Monoid` is precisely the type class you're looking for.  For your case, you'd be able to implement it like this:

```
newtype Valuater = Valuater {
    evalValuater :: A -> [Int]
    }

instance Monoid Valuater where
    mempty = Valuater (const [])
    mappend (Valuater f) (Valuater g) = Valuater (\a -> f a ++ g a)
    mconcat vs = Valuater (\a -> concatMap (`evalValuater` a) vs)
```

Then you can use all the `Monoid` related functions on `Valuaters`.

In fact, you can make this a bit more general:

```
newtype Valuater' m = Valuater {
    evalValuater :: A -> m
    }

instance Monoid m => Monoid (Valuater' m) where
    mempty = Valuater (const mempty)
    mappend (Valuater f) (Valuater g) = Valuater (\a -> f a <> g a)
    mconcat vs = Valuater (\a -> mconcat $ map (`evalValuater` a) vs)

type Valuater = Valuater' [Int]
```

And now you can have a `Valuater'` work across different monoids very easily, but I don't know if this is particularly useful for approaching your specific problem.

Comment: I believe your explicit instances are equivalent to those you would get with `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`. Which means the `Monoid` for the `type` in the original question is already defined.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen probably, but I think it's important to show the explicit implementation as well, since it can help in understanding how Monoids work under the hood.

Answer (score 9):

Most likely you'd like to take a look at `Monoid`

```
class Monoid a where
  mempty :: a
  mappend :: a -> a -> a
  mconcat :: [a] -> a
```